# if(isTesting==false) ? if(false==isTesting) ? if(!isTesting) ? which is the best way of programming

Tags: java

Few years back I was writing code for conditional check as like below

```
boolean isTesting ==false;
if(isTesting==false)
```

And one fine day one of senior guy came to me and told me this is not efficient way to do. And then explained something about this to me. I heard But I guess didn’t listened. 
So I started to write like as below without knowing the purpose of it.

```
if(false==isTesting)
```

Now sudden curiosity came on this subject again is really efficient!? which one is best way to do so?

`if(isTesting==false)` ?
`if(false==isTesting)` ? 
`if(!isTesting)` ?

And same doubt about `if(null==value)` and `if(value==null)`. Please clarify

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Best way: `if(!isTesting)`

Comment: that is just the Joda pattern

Comment: `if(!isTesting)` is clearer than the others.

Comment: This has nothing to do with efficiency.

Comment: `if (false==isTesting)` prevents you from writting `if (isTesting=false)` by mistake, instead of `if (isTesting==false)`.

Comment: No no no, the best way is: `if (isTesting & isTesting == isTesting ^ isTesting)`.

Comment: @Andremoniy LOL, that is easy to read and very efficient. You made my project super fast ;)

Answer (score 4):

```
if (isTesting == false)
```

is a bit dangerous, because you could forget an `=` sign and write

```
if (isTesting = false)
```

which compiles (it assigns false to `isTesting`, and evaluates to false).

```
if (false == isTesting)
```

avoids the problem because forgetting an `=` would make the code invalid. But it's much too verbose, and compares what is already a boolean to another boolean, to produce a boolean. So

```
if (!isTesting)
```

does the same thing, shows that you understand what a booelan expression is, and doesn't have the risk of forgetting an `=`. You should of course prefer this last way.

Writing

```
if (null == value)
```

is unnecessary, because forgetting an equal in

```
if (value = null)
```

would cause the code to become invalid. `value = null` is not a boolean expession (unless value is of type `Boolean`). So use `value == null`, which is more natural.

Anyway, unless you frequently switch to a language that uses `=` instead of `==` for comparisons, you normally won't forget to use `==` instead of `=`. It becomes natural after a few days. Good IDEs and code quality tools warn you when you use `=` instead of `==` in a boolean expression.

Answer (score 1):

The best of these is `if (!isTesting)` as it's simplest and cleanest.

Of the other two options `if (value==null)` is
more natural so I would recommend using that one.

Answer (score 0):

Functionally they are all equivalent.

That said, the recommendation to write the constant / literal on the left side of the == is motivated by the impossibility to accidentially write = (assignment) instead of == (equality). Since you can't assign to a constant / literal the compiler would complain if you accidentially wrote =.

The short, concise !expression has no such problems, and it furthermore makes it totally obvious that expression *must* evaluate to a boolean (everything else would be a compile error). So a simple if (boolean) / if (!boolean) is commonly considered the most logical idiom.